# How To Compile Assets In Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, asset-pipeline, laravel-8

I am working on Laravel v8, but I was surprised why composer did not install minified CSS and JavaScript files. I'm using the latest version of composer (2.0.13) and PhpStorm. Do I have to add these files manually or what?

Comment: Please share more details. Composer is a PHP package manager, and usually does not know anything about CSS or JS

Comment: I'm installing Laravel via composer (composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name). After installing Laravel when I opened it in phpstorm and looking at app.css files under css folder in resources director it's empty . Similarly in the js file under js folder there's only one line mentioned " require('./bootstrap'); ". Why it happened while when I see in the instructor lecture (they're using laravel 5.x) everything is correct there.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. And why don't you ask your instructor about that? If they are using Laravel v5, and you are using Laravel v8, that might cause a huge difference

Comment: Mrs. Haase,

I just want to add bootstrap into my Laravel project. I just visit the documentation and they said to install npm and run npm stuff like that. And discuss the process of installing Tailwind CSS. I visit some sites and found the steps write in the answer.

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix for the recommended approach for this.

Answer (score -1):

After creating the Laravel -v8 project and going into the project directory, use the following commands to add Bootstrap and your desire libraries,

Step 1. Install Laravel/UI

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Step 2.  Install Bootstrap in Laravel

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Step 3. Install your project's frontend dependencies

```
npm install
```

Step 4. Compiling asset

```
npm run dev
```

[image]

Now you can use Bootstrap’s compiled JS and CSS in your application.

[image]

If you want to install more packages for instance for React packages
you can use the following command in step 2

```
php artisan ui react
```